# Jersey 2 client for StreamingOutput

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I have a `Jersey` service that output binary data as `StreamingOutput`,  `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM`.

How to implement a client using `Jersey` 2 for handling the `response` from such service?

Comment: There is a Client API section in Jersey Docs, look at this example: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e4349

Answer (score 1):

Below is one way of implementing Jersey 2 client for downloading a file from a REST service which is returning binary data as `StreamingOutput` with `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM` -

```
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    // change SERVER_URL, API_PATH and PATH as per REST API details
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target(SERVER_URL).path(API_PATH).path(PATH);

    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request();
    Response response = invocationBuilder.get();

    String contentDispositionHeader = response.getHeaderString("Content-Disposition");
    String fileName = contentDispositionHeader
            .substring(contentDispositionHeader.indexOf("filename=") + "filename=".length()).replace("\"", "");

    InputStream responseStream = response.readEntity(InputStream.class);

    // Set location here where you want to store downloaded file. 
    // It will replace the file if already exist in that location with same name.
    Files.copy(responseStream, Paths.get("H:/"+ fileName), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

    System.out.println("File is downloaded");
```